# sequelize migration problem ERROR: the "Customer" relationship does not exist

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, migration, database-migration

I am trying to migrate my database in postgresql to heroku but I am getting an error at the time of the many to many relationship in my payment model, I am testing the migration first in my local database.

when i run the comand npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
i got

```js
npx: installed 80 in 43.54s

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.18.1, CLI: 6.3.0, ORM: 6.7.0].

Loaded configuration file "appconfig.js".
== 2021101024193237-create-user: migrating =======
== 2021102424193237-create-user: migrated (0.314s)

== 2021102424195115-create-product-type: migrated =======
== 2021102424195115-create-product-type: migrated (0.099s)

== 2021102424195210-create-customer: migrating =======
== 2021101024195210-create-customer: migrated (0.326s)

== 2021102424195554-create-product: migrating =======
== 2021102424195554-create-product: migrated (0.260s)

== 20211027140837-create-payment: migrating =======

ERROR: the "Customer" relationship does not exist.
```

this my model

```js
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Payment extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Payment.belongsToMany(models.Product_Payment, {
        through: "Invoice",
        onDelete:"CASCADE"
      });
      Payment.belongsTo(models.Customer,{
        as:'client',
        foreignKey:'customer_id',
        sourceKey:'id'
      });
    }
  };

  Payment.init({
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    payment_type:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    iva:{
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      validate:{
        isNumeric: true,
        isEven(value) {
          if (value < 0.5) {
            throw new Error('IVA must be 0.5 or higher');
          }
        }
      },
    },
    sub_total:{
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      validate:{
        isNumeric: true,
      },
    },
    total:{
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      validate:{
        isNumeric: true,
      },
    },
    status:{ //pago o no 
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    },
    customer_id:{
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },

  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Payment',
  });
  return Payment;
};
```

and my customer model here

```js
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  
  class Customer extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
      Customer.hasMany(models.Payment, {
        as:'client', 
        foreignKey:'customer_id',
        sourceKey:'id'
      });
    }
  };
  Customer.init({

    id:{
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate:{
        notEmpty(value){
          if(value == "" || value ==" " || value ==null || value ==undefined){
            throw new Error('Cant be null or empty');
          }
        },
        notSpecial(value){
          if(value.includes("<") || value.includes(">")){
            throw new Error('especial characters not allow!');
          }
        },
      }
    },
    ci:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique:true,
      validate:{
        is: /^[V|E]-[0-9]{5,9}$/gim, 
        notEmpty(value){
          if(value == "" || value ==" " || value ==null || value ==undefined){
            throw new Error('Cant be null or empty');
          }
        },
        notSpecial(value){
          if(value.includes("<") || value.includes(">")){
            throw new Error('especial characters not allow!');
          }
        },
      }
    },
    email:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique:true,
      validate:{
        isEmail: true,
        notEmpty(value){
          if(value == "" || value ==" " || value ==null || value ==undefined){
            throw new Error('Cant be null or empty');
          }
        },
        notSpecial(value){
          if(value.includes("<") || value.includes(">")){
            throw new Error('especial characters not allow!');
          }
        },
      },
    },
    phone_number:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique:true,
      validate:{
        len: [11],
        notEmpty(value){
          if(value == "" || value ==" " || value ==null || value ==undefined){
            throw new Error('Cant be null or empty');
          }
        },
        notSpecial(value){
          if(value.includes("<") || value.includes(">")){
            throw new Error('especial characters not allow!');
          }
        },
      }
    },
    address:{
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true,
      validate:{
        notSpecial(value){
          if(value.includes("<") || value.includes(">")){
            throw new Error('especial characters not allow!');
          }
        },
      }
    },
    qrcode: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      // allowNull defaults to true
    },
    active: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      // allowNull defaults to true
    },

  }, { sequelize,modelName: 'Customer'});
  return Customer;
};
```

and also my migrate js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Payments', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      payment_type:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING
      },
      iva:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.FLOAT,
        validate:{
          isNumeric: true,
          isEven(value) {
            if (value < 0.5) {
              throw new Error('IVA must be 0.5 or higher');
            }
          }
        },
      },
      sub_total:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.FLOAT,
        validate:{
          isNumeric: true,
        },
      },
      total:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.FLOAT,
        validate:{
          isNumeric: true,
        },
      },
      status:{ //pago o no 
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      },
      customer_id:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          through: 'Invoice',
          model: 'Customer',
          key: 'id'
        },
        allowNull: false
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Payments');
  }
};
```

edit: customer migration

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Customers', {
      id:{
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate:{
          notEmpty(value){
            if(value == "" || value ==" " || value ==null || value ==undefined){
              throw new Error('Cant be null or empty');
            }
          },
          notSpecial(value){
            if(value.includes("<") || value.includes(">")){
              throw new Error('especial characters not allow!');
            }
          },
        }
      },
      ci:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique:true,
        validate:{
          is: /^[V|E]-[0-9]{5,9}$/gim, 
          notEmpty(value){
            if(value == "" || value ==" " || value ==null || value ==undefined){
              throw new Error('Cant be null or empty');
            }
          },
          notSpecial(value){
            if(value.includes("<") || value.includes(">")){
              throw new Error('especial characters not allow!');
            }
          },
        }
      },
      email:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique:true,
        validate:{
          isEmail: true,
          notEmpty(value){
            if(value == "" || value ==" " || value ==null || value ==undefined){
              throw new Error('Cant be null or empty');
            }
          },
          notSpecial(value){
            if(value.includes("<") || value.includes(">")){
              throw new Error('especial characters not allow!');
            }
          },
        },
      },
      phone_number:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
        unique:true,
        validate:{
          len: [11],
          notEmpty(value){
            if(value == "" || value ==" " || value ==null || value ==undefined){
              throw new Error('Cant be null or empty');
            }
          },
          notSpecial(value){
            if(value.includes("<") || value.includes(">")){
              throw new Error('especial characters not allow!');
            }
          },
        }
      },
      address:{
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: true,
        validate:{
          notSpecial(value){
            if(value.includes("<") || value.includes(">")){
              throw new Error('especial characters not allow!');
            }
          },
        }
      },
      qrcode: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.TEXT,
        // allowNull defaults to true
      },
      active: {
        type: Sequelize.DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        // allowNull defaults to true
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Customers');
  }
};
```

Comment: Please show the migration with Customer

Comment: done  watch the edit

Comment: Did you try to indicate ` model: 'Customers',` just to check if it's the case?

Comment: Yeah I already tried

Comment: And what error did you get in this case?

Comment: Same error  jajaja

Comment: About 'Customer' and not about 'Customers' this time?

Comment: yep thats it dud

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I suppose you need to prepare a minimal reproducible project with all migrations. And also you need to indicate what DB you use